# Error in make htmldocs Linux kernel

Tags: linux, latex-base

I am trying to compile make htmldocs in linux kernel 5.2.2 version.

Facing some issues

```
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Index file 'networking.idx' was written
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'networking.ind' from line
  'No file networking.ind.'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'networking.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'networking.pdf' failed
make[2]: *** [networking.pdf] Error 12
Documentation/Makefile:90: recipe for target 'pdfdocs' failed
make[1]: *** [pdfdocs] Error 2
Makefile:1548: recipe for target 'pdfdocs' failed
make: *** [pdfdocs] Error 2
```

Anybody have idea on this ?